# Are there any non-cosmetic differences among quartz countertops?

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops, quartz

I'm planning to get a quartz countertop. One contractor told me that all brands of quartz are the same quality since they use the same patented process. Two other contractors told me there is a quality difference among brands. I've looked online and haven't found any definitive answer

**Is there a quality difference in quartz from different companies, or are the differences only cosmetic?** My highest priorities are durability and ease of care.

Comment: https://www.hanstonequartz.com/blogs/blog/problems-with-chinese-quartz-countertops.  Yes there can be huge quality differences since quartz is manufactured product subject to mistakes and shortcuts being made during the process China made quartz is becoming very common and there are issues with lots of the stuff made there.

Comment: @kris thanks, although I tend to be suspicious of claims on a manufacturer's or retailer's website. Do you think this is trustworthy?

Comment: Generally speaking, there will be quality differences between two examples of anything from different sources (manufactured or dug out of the ground).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are polyesther , often called "epoxy", with silica/quartz fill. Different grades of polyesther are used , cheaper ones are diluted with more styrene monomer. And different concentrations of fill. An installer could likely give an objective evaluation of different brands. However, ours were made at a local shop that I visited and I could imagine there is some difference depending of the operator ( for locally produced tops).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with quartz I suggest Silestone. I worked with it for years and it is very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are definite differences in the quality of Quartz, the amount of epoxy fillers, etc.  For the most part, silestone, Caesarstone, and cambria offer the highest quality.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Do you have any references that would back this up? It's not that I doubt you, however, as it stands, this is "just something some guy on the internet said". References would give it much more substance. Feel free to [edit] them into your post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).